# DateFns long format not working with PPPPpppp

Tags: javascript, date-fns

PPPPpppp just gives me `PPPPpppp`

`dateFns.format(new Date(), 'PPPPpppp')`

Loading from cdn with:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.min.js" integrity="sha512-F+u8eWHrfY8Xw9BLzZ8rG/0wIvs0y+JyRJrXjp    3VjtFPylAEEGwKbua5Ip/oiVhaTDaDs4eU2Xtsxjs/9ag2bQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>`

Output I get is just `PPPPpppp`